# Experimental calculation of dc motor resistance

Tags: dc-motor, basic

I am trying to calculate resistance of DC motor experimentally.

I have measured voltage and current for different voltages applied (from -5V to 5 V). Motor shaft is blocked.

And the question is why resistance is smaller for higher voltages? (resistance according to applied voltage is decreasing)

Comment: Is the motor allowed to turn freely?

Comment: Sorry I have forgotten to add. I have blocked shaft. Motor is not allowed to turn. I have edited question.

Comment: When the armature is allowed to turn, it develops Counter EMF and the apparent resistance is increased.

Comment: Resistance is smaller for higher voltages? Says who? Maybe you should present your experimental setup and results in more detail.

Comment: Setup is very easy I measure current and set voltage. Then calculate Resistance it varies from 8,61 Ohm (for 5 V) to 10 Ohm (for 1 V). Shaft is blocked during measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some accidental experimental error here : You may expect to measure the resistance of just a set of windings, and that should be constant regardless of the drive voltage.

However unless you have locked the shaft AND kept it locked throughout the series of measurements, you may see something different. Measure at a specific voltage, and rotate the shaft very slowly by hand (if its a low power motor : otherwise take proper safety precautions and use a low voltage!)

You will probably see the resistance measurements fluctuate as brushes make and break contact with commutator segments. You may see the resistance halve briefly as one winding connects before the previous one disconnects.

Maybe this is what you are seeing in your series of measurements?

Comment: I asked this question because i see some tendence in data - 1V:10Ohm, 2V:9.39Ohm, 3V:8.72Ohm, 4V:8.51V, 5V:8.61V, so I thought it can be explained.

Comment: My answer is the only explanation I can think of. Your measurements show higher resistance at 5V than at 4V which adds some weight to the possibility of experimental error.

Comment: What order did you make the measurements in?  Resistance changes with temperature, so if you locked the rotor and then applied voltage, the current will heat the magnet wire up.  Higher temps = more resistance.  This could account for some of the differences as well.